# Java Multithreading for Clock Based Emulation

Tags: java, multithreading

What I want to do is to use Threads to simulate a clock based hardware system. Underneath you can see what I already tried with no avail:

```
while (true)
{
    Thread.sleep(0L, 1L);
    synchronized (thread)
    {
        thread.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

And the following in the `Thread` that is waiting for the clock:

```
// Do something before waiting.
System.out.println("Taking a nap!");
// And then wait for the clock.
synchronized (thread)
{
    tick.wait();
}
```

The problem I encountered is that when I use the `Thread.sleep(long, long)` method, I have to be sure that any notified `Thread` ran before waiting for the next tick. And the `Thread.sleep(long, long)` method is too slow or the calling `Thread` has such a long time sleeping that even a single nanosecond causes the system to stutter.

I already tried something like similar to what is shown underneath to get arround the `Thread.sleep(long, long)` method, but that sometimes causes the clock to tick at random without any `Thread` reacting to that:

```
while (cpu.getThread().getState() != Thread.State.WAITING && ppu.getThread().getState() != Thread.State.WAITING);
```

Back to the original question, is there any way to improve the code shown above in any way? Can I resolve the issue without using any `Thread` whatsoever?

Comment: Could you share a complete and verifiable example so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Not an expert on it, but I'm not sure sleeping for 1 nanosecond is really going to be very accurate. It's probably going to suspend the thread and then wake it immediately, but I bet that takes longer than a nanosecond. You might want to write a test that prints the current time (very accurately), then does your little sleep thread for, say, 10,000 times, then prints the time. See how much time really elapsed.

Comment: @JosephLarson yes i know but the sleep works because the scheduler invokes other threads in that moment, only problem is that it is to slow, but when i do something that is faster, often i do ticks that dont wake up the waiting threads

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-producer-multi-consumer problem. We need a mechanism to keep all thread's execution states. So if object wait/notifyAll were to be used:

producer thread:

```
// map to contain all the consumer threads, true to indicate it's waiting
Map<Thread, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Thread, Boolean>();
while (true)
{
    synchronized (tick)
    {
        if (allValuesInMapAreTrue(map)) {
            for (Thread thread : map.keySet()) {
                map.put(thread, false);
            }
            tick.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

consumer thread:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        doSomething();
        waitForTick();
    }
}

public void waitForTick()
{
    synchronized (tick)
    {
        try {
            Thread curr = Thread.currentThread();
            map.put(curr, true);
            tick.wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

better yet. Check out Condition in Java:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

Comment: This is kind of what i am doing, the problem is that sometimes after notifyAll, the producer ceep running i guess, so it gose back to check if everyone is waiting and because no one else runed yet they are all still waiting and the producer notify again

Comment: I see, the scheduler may let producer reenter the synchronized block again immediately after it left. Edit the code to use map instead of set to track the consumer status then